# How to modify the appearance of equation numbers

Tags: equation-number

My Latex code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}

\makeatletter
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\subsection{Subsection A}
\begin{equation}
    E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\subsection{Subsection B}
\begin{equation}
    F = ma
\end{equation}

\section{Second Section}
\begin{equation}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**Current output**

```
1 First Section
1.1 Subsection A
    E = mc2      (1.1.1)
1.2 Subsection B
    F = ma       (1.2.1)
2 Second Section
    a2 + b2 = c2 (2.0.1)
```

**But the required output is**

```
1 First Section
1.1 Subsection A
    E = mc2       (1.1.1)
1.2 Subsection B
    F = ma        (1.2.1)
2 Second Section
    a2 + b2 = c2    (2.1)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just want to equation number (2.1) instead of (2.0.1)

Comment: Off-topic: The preamble of the test document shown above could be simplified to `\usepackage{amsmath} \numberwithin{equation}{subsection}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution does what the OP wants, *viz.*, to show the value of the `subsection` counter in the composite equation number *unless* this value is equal to zero -- which will be the case if a `\section` directive but no `\subsection` directive has been issued of late.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for \numberwithin macro
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\let\origtheequation\theequation % store the default format

\renewcommand{\theequation}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \origtheequation % use default format
  \else \thesection.\arabic{equation} % use a simplified format
  \fi}

\setlength\textwidth{3.5in} % just for this example

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\subsection{Subsection A}
Some words\dots
\begin{equation} E = mc^2 \end{equation}

\subsection{Subsection B}
Some words\dots
\begin{equation} F = ma \end{equation}

\section{Second Section}
Some words\dots
\begin{equation} a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `'
I am really sorry, 
I just Update my output:
1 First Section
1.1 Subsection A
    E = mc2 (1.1.1)
1.2 Subsection B
    F = ma (1.2.1)
2 Second Section
    a2 + b2 = c2 (2.1`
 can you fix it again, please?

Comment: @Md.AbdeMannaf - I've updated my answer per your request.

Comment: Thank you, dear @Mico.

Comment: @Md.AbdeMannaf - I've applied one final little fix to my code.